# Ckeditor, let user insert into predefined elements in template

Tags: templates, ckeditor, restrict

Using CKeditor is it possible to create a template, and only let users edit certain elements in it while keeping the structure intact?

For example a header, a subtext, a paragraph and list of items. But they mustn't delete any of these or add other elements.

The use case is that users have to create a bunch of documents that has to look a certain way. They aren't allowed to veer from the standard layouts.

Or is that use case beyond the scope of the editor?
I can't seem to find examples of this in their documentation.

The alternative could be to create custom forms in html on the left side of the page and simultaneously update a "read only" document on the right side of the page so that they can "preview" the final document in CKeditor.

Though just letting users edit a "locked" template would be a smoother experience.

-Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at widgets. Online demo of a sample widget (explained in a tutorial) with predefined structure is available here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/simplebox.html